# Flex - Date serialization

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Does anyone know how to get actionscript to render a null date value '000:00:00T00:00:00'? I am calling a web service that expects date fields in the SOAP xml. I need some of these dates to serialize as null and I can't see how to produce null. The closest value I can get is '1899-11-30T00:00:00Z'.  Below is the code I am using:

var dateStr:String = "0000-00-00T00:00:00+";
  var emptyDate:Date = DateUtil.parseW3CDTF(dateStr); 
  newReqData.DateTimeInit = emptyDate;

Comment: what is the type of DateTimeInit ? Isn't there a way to initialize otherwise than by passing a Date (which is hardly set to 0000...)

Comment: The type is Date. The problem I am having is not with formatting, it is with the serialization. I want the SOAP call to render the universal NULL date, which I believe is '0000-00-00T00:00:00'. My .Net implementation of this web service call renders this value in the XML post. The Flex implementation does not. It renders '1899-11-30T00:00:00Z'. So the end result is that I get a date of '11/30/1899' in the database which is not desireable. With the .Net implementation, I get a nice NULL in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with a date formatter.  You'll have to create a Date object but if you pass it to the DateFormatter, you can set the format to pretty much whatever you like.  Here's the reference and I would recommend looking at the "Other Text" area:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html

Comment: The problem I am having is not with formatting, it is with the serialization. I want the SOAP call to render the universal NULL date, which I believe is '0000-00-00T00:00:00'. My .Net implementation of this web service call renders this value in the XML post. The Flex implementation does not. It renders '1899-11-30T00:00:00Z'. So the end result is that I get a date of '11/30/1899' in the database which is not desireable. With the .Net implementation, I get a nice NULL in the database.

Comment: I've run into Date type conversion problems before with .Net.  Many of these actually come from the start date each system (.Net and Flex) use as a base.  I've never actually come across a need to pass a NULL date object(and can't really think of how/why I would need to).  If your .Net is inserting a NULL value into the db, perhaps passing it as a NULL from Flex isn't the best approach.  Either that or you could check for the 1899 value and simply handle it server-side.

Comment: You could also try passing a string from Flex and parsing it into a date server-side.  Just out of curiosity, if the value is NULL from Flex, why are you passing it at all?

Comment: I am calling a web service provied by a commercial product, so I have no control in changing it on server side. The WSDL, which I have no control over expects a 'date' type, so I can't pass it a string. (tried that) The WSDL exposes data structures which I am populating and handing back as parameter in service method. The data structure has many date fields. (about 15) In my .Net project which calls this same web service, I don't populate the date fields and the SOAP xml renders this NULL date value that I eluded to earlier. And a NULL results in the DB. Flex forces me to populate the date.

Comment: I totally understand and it's a tough position.  Have you looked into WebOrb.net?  I haven't dug into it, but there might be something there that can help.  Unfortunately, the Date base class in Flex is final so you can't extend it.  I tried several approaches and, much like you, I was only able to get back to 1899.  I'll keep digging around, but I'm at a loss on this one.

Comment: We are thinking that the solution may be to create a trigger in the database that changes the Flex date of '1899-11-30T00:00:00Z' to a NULL value. This is 'clugy' but will solve our problem.

Answer (score 0):

var d:Date=new Date();
d.setTime(-62167226400000);
Alert.show(d.toString());

or as said Shawn Yale, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560542/flex-date-serialization/3562183#3562183).